# java 8 find out size of metaspace at runtime

Tags: java, java-8, metaspace

Java 8 uses metaspace that is capable of expanding dynamically. GC will run on metaspace when its getting full. Does that mean GC will never run on metaspace?

My Java 8 application is using a LOT of memory. I would like to know what is the size of my metaspace at the run time. How do I do that?

I am thinking of setting `MaxMetaspaceSize`. What should I set it to? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 25):

**Option 1:**

Execute

```
jstat -gc PID
```

(with PID replaced by the PID of the JVM to monitor) which will return sth. like:

```
S0C      S1C       S0U   S1U     EC       EU        OC         OU        MC       MU       CCSC    CCSU       YGC   YGCT     FGC    FGCT    GCT
103936.0 107008.0  0.0   41618.3 820736.0 401794.3  444928.0   183545.7  181888.0 137262.8 28544.0 20386.6    313   16.024   8      3.706   19.729
```

According to [this](http://xmlandmore.blogspot.de/2014/08/jstat-tool-new-metaspace-statistics.html) of interest are:

```
MC: Metaspace capacity (kB)
MU: Metaspace utilization (kB)
```

So in this case about 181mb of Metaspace are committed while 137mb are used currently.

**Option 2:**

If you have garbage collection logs enabled you can also find this out from there, e.g. after the application crashed already or an issue was reported.
Search for lines like

```
2016-04-06T01:50:04.842+0200: 7.795: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)
[PSYoungGen: 7139K->0K(177152K)]
[ParOldGen: 18396K->22213K(101888K)] 25535K->22213K(279040K), 
[Metaspace: 34904K->34904K(1081344K)], 0.1408610 secs]
[Times: user=0.45 sys=0.00, real=0.14 secs]
```

This constitutes a resizing of the Metaspace as the previous threshold was reached.

```
[Metaspace: 34904K->34904K(1081344K)], 0.1408610 secs]
```

contains the relevant information: 34,9mb were used before as well as after GC.
The latest of these log entries you can find will show the current size (that is: after GC).

Keep in mind that full GC is run whenever Metaspace is resized. So its a good idea to configure a good start value for this when you already know that the default value of ~21mb (depending on Host configuration) is not enough.

See [this](http://xmlandmore.blogspot.de/2014/08/hotspot-case-study-of-tuning.html) for more information on tuning Metaspace size.

Comment: `man jstat` gives the correct interpretations of "MC: Metaspace capacity (kB)" and "MU: Metacspace utilization (kB)", not "committed" and "used".

Answer (score 19):

```
for (MemoryPoolMXBean memoryMXBean : ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()) {
    if ("Metaspace".equals(memoryMXBean.getName())) {
            System.out.println(memoryMXBean.getUsage().getUsed()/1024/1024 + " mb");
    }
}
```

Yes, it is better to set `MaxMetaspaceSize` if you think it is leaky to monitor and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Use jcmd. It's the best built-in oracle tool for finding this stuff in Java 8. From terminal...

NOTE: you need to run jcmd as whatever user started the java process. If you are debugging a webserver like Jetty you may need to change user with something like `sudo su jetty`.

1. Run `jcmd`
2. Take the PID displayed for your app and run `jcmd <pid> VM.native_memory`
   [image]
   This has
3. For more options run `jcmd <pid> help`

Comment: that also rrequires NMT to be turned on.

Comment: `jcmd <pid> GC.heap_info` will give you basic info about Metaspace size and doesn't require NMT being enabled.

Comment: any idea when heap_info was added, it's not present in 8 u25?

Comment: `jinfo -flag MaxMetaspaceSize <pid>` also doesn't require NMT

Comment: @Chris _GC.heap_info_ was added in jdk9-b94, see [JDK-8059036](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8059036) and [jdk/commit/3b63ebf830734aab17c085f86fde4b1bed26c0a4](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/3b63ebf830734aab17c085f86fde4b1bed26c0a4)